# InvalidOperationException: Se detectó una referencia circular al serializar un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Trato de enlistar los Perfiles que tiene un usuario pero no puedo, hay el error de referencia circular, trato de obtener al mismo usuario y luego seleccionarlo pero el problema es el mismo.

Ambos modelos fueron generador por `DataEntity Framework` y esta e sl acual trato de obtenerlo

```
        ViewBag.lista = db.tb_usuario.Include("tb_perfil").Where(a => a.nombre == id).FirstOrDefault();
        //return View();
        return Json(ViewBag.lista,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Usuario**

```
public partial class tb_usuario
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int dni { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string usuario { get; set; }
    public string clave { get; set; }
    public bool estado { get; set; }
    public int perfil_id { get; set; }
    public int usuario_id_registro { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime fecha_registro { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> usuario_id_modifica { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> fecha_modifica { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> usuario_id_elimina { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> fecha_elimina { get; set; }

    public virtual tb_perfil tb_perfil { get; set; }
}
```

**Perfil**

```
public partial class tb_perfil
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tb_perfil()
    {
        this.tb_usuario = new HashSet<tb_usuario>();
        this.tb_menu = new HashSet<tb_menu>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public bool estado { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tb_usuario> tb_usuario { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tb_menu> tb_menu { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema de **referencia circular** que estás teniendo se debe al **Lazy-Loading**, que viene establecido a **True** por defecto en EF.

Para deshabilitar este comportamiento, debes hacerlo antes de traer el `Usuario` de la BD de la siguiente manera:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
ViewBag.lista = db.tb_Usuario.Include(x => x.tb_perfil).Where(a => a.nombre == id).FirstOrDefault();
```